# return @@rowcount result on SQL query

Tags: sql-server, rowcount, raiserror

I wanted to raiserror `if exists` and then `print` the number of rows that are matching .But this doesnt work . Please help .

```
if exists (select * from [rto] a
     inner join rt b
     on a.NUM=b.TABLE_NAME
     where a.START_YEAR between b.YEAR_START and b.YEAR_STOP)
     Raiserror ('Matched recs found',16,1)
     print 'There are' +  cast(@@rowcount as varchar(20)) + 'matched rows'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an alternative to your original post...not sure if you have specific requirements, but this should get you the error output that you desire:

```
DECLARE @rowcount INT
SET @rowcount = (select COUNT(*) from [rto] a
    inner join rt b
    on a.NUM=b.TABLE_NAME
    where a.START_YEAR between b.YEAR_START and b.YEAR_STOP)
IF @rowcount > 0
BEGIN
    Raiserror ('Matched recs found',16,1)
    print 'There are ' +  cast(@rowcount as varchar(20)) + ' matched rows'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `BEGIN` and `END`:

```
if exists (select * from [rto] a
    inner join rt b
    on a.NUM=b.TABLE_NAME
    where a.START_YEAR between b.YEAR_START and b.YEAR_STOP)
BEGIN
    Raiserror ('Matched recs found',16,1)
    print 'There are ' +  cast(@@rowcount as varchar(20)) + ' matched rows'
END
```

Comment: Thanks but it is returning zero but I can see there are matched records .